# JavaScript and CSS files are cached by the browser by default?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, caching, web-applications

As per my understanding files are cached by the browser by default. Developers don't have to set specific
headers to enable the caching of these files. Right?

If yes, how come browser know that it has to enable caching for specific types of files only not for servlet/jsp calls. For example :- if i make call to same servlet
request goes to server side and fresh page is served (not the browser cached paged).

Comment: Also depends on the type of request. For instance, `GET` requests are cached by default whilst `POST` request are not.

Comment: HTTP Cache headers: http://bit.ly/11cKyW3

Comment: @jAndy Thanks jAndy. But i believe GET request are cached only for static contents like css,jss,html. What about servlet/JSP requests